# convert mysql code to codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How can i convert this code into an acceptable codeigniter code:

```
mysql_select_db($database_connection_ched, $connection_ched);
$query_Institutions = "SELECT * FROM tb_institutional_profile ORDER BY tb_institutional_profile.institution_name ASC";
$Institutions = mysql_query($query_Institutions, $connection_ched) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Institutions = mysql_fetch_assoc($Institutions);
$totalRows_Institutions = mysql_num_rows($Institutions);

<td width="192"><select name="institution_id">
<?php 
do { 
<option value="<?php echo $row_Institutions['institution_id']?>" ><?php echo $row_Institutions['institution_name']?></option>
<?php
} while ($row_Institutions = mysql_fetch_assoc($Institutions));
?>
</select></td>
```

Comment: i'm not really sure. and i'm going into circles.. tried to put the mysql code in a model function. then called it in the view. but no joy :( i'm lost. badly need some help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, set your `database.php` correctly in `application/config/` folder, and then either autoload or use `$this->load->database();` on your controller/model

```
<?php

$this->db->order_by("institution_name", "asc"); 
$result = $this->db->get('tb_institutional_profile');

$totalRows_Institutions = $this->db->count_all_results();

?>

<td width="192"><select name="institution_id">
    <?php 
        foreach($result->result() as $row ){
            ?>
            <option value="<?= $row->institution_id ?>">
            <?= $row->institution_name ?>
            </option>
            <?php
        } 
    ?>
</td>
```

Comment: it worked. thank you very much sir. actually db is already setup.

Comment: Additional question. I have another similar code for a dropdown in the same form. please see this [screenshot](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20121009-u7eh-38kb.jpg) and made some changes to fetch db in Region (from tb_region table). but i'm getting an error on the institute. those this code co exist if they are called similarly identical?

Comment: according to your screenshot it looks like theres no such item in $result object. You can try to print_r() $result and see what variables you get with that other query.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tb_institutional_profile');
    $this->db->order_by('tb_institutional_profile.institution_name','ASC');
    $query                  = $this->db->get();
    $res                    = $query->result();
    $totalRows_Institutions = $query->num_rows()


    $result  = "<td width='192'>";
    $result .= "<select name='institution_id'>";
  foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $result .="<option value='".$row->institution_id."'>'".$row->institution_name."'</option>'";
  }
    $result .= "</select>";
    $result .= "</td>";

return $result;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this. But still i got an error. Maybe on the <td> part. because i think there is no  $row_Institutions = mysql_fetch_assoc($Institutions); in the mysql code. appreciate it